# Epicor in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, virtualization, epicorerp

I was wondering how can I use **Epicor** 10 in Windows Azure.

I want to install the app server on Windows Azure, all the Epicor 10 components, when it's all done and ready, I would like to use normal PC's to conenct to the app server[Windows Azure], download Epicor Client and use it on the client PC's.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a reasonable setup to me.  Epicor 10 hosted on an azure vm should work similarly to an install on a conventional server.  Here is some microsoft documentation on creating azure vms: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/virtual-machines/

For a standard install, you should follow the microsoft tutorial as necessary along with the specifications set in the Epicor 10 hardware sizing guide (apply this to your vm creation) and Epicor 10 server implementation guide available on Epicweb.

You're probably aware of this if you're already in process for implementing E10 on Azure, but for preliminary concepts of Epicor on Windows Azure and explanation of Epicor working on azure, there's a presentation which is useful for slides 17-20ish and 37: https://epicweb.epicor.com/resources/MRCCustomers/Embracing%20the%20Cloud%20-%20Leveraging%20the%20Microsoft%20Azure%20Platform%20to%20Evolve%20your%20Business.pptx
You'll have to login to your epicweb account.